# JNDI binding EJB3 issues

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi, ejb-3.0, stateless-session-bean

I am stuck on a JNDI binding process on EJB3 and here is the source code which I am terribly stuck at.

```
/*
     * Create session bean.
     */
    public static AG20BWOPortal getSessionBean() throws NamingException, RemoteException, CreateException{
        if(wo == null){
            Context ic = new InitialContext();
            System.out.println("test1");
            Object obj = ic.lookup("ejb/sg/gov/hdb/ag20/ejb/AG20BWOPortalHome");  //JNDI name (from EJB module xmi file)
            System.out.println("test2");
            AG20BWOPortalHome home = (AG20BWOPortalHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj, AG20BWOPortalHome.class);
            wo = home.create();
        }
        return wo;
    }
```

My questions are

- The home interface is removed as part of EJB3 migration process,
  hence how do I replace the home interfaces?
- How do I bind in EJB3 standard?

Comment: Which application server are you using?  What does your EJB look like?  When you say "how do I bind", do you mean "how do I lookup"?  Note that JNDI lookup names were vendor-specific prior to EJB 3.1

Comment: I am sorry to keep this hanging - I would like to mention that this had been solved and post the solutions soon enough :)

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this on my own if anyone want to catch the drift of how I did this.

1. EJB Implementation Class -> @Stateless Annotation
2. EJB Remote Interface -> @Remote Annotation

This would bind the EJB classes together.

PS: Do not forget to remove the extends from EJB's remote interface as well.